# Why is my didBeginContact function detecting way too many collisions?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, xcode7, skphysicsbody

My didBeginContact function is detecting about 60 collisions between two SKSpriteNodes when there should only be one.

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let firstBody = contact.bodyA
    let secondBody = contact.bodyB
    if firstBody.categoryBitMask == bulletCategory && secondBody.categoryBitMask == dragonCategory || firstBody.categoryBitMask == dragonCategory && secondBody.categoryBitMask == bulletCategory{

        print("collision happened")
    }
}
```

When the nodes come into contact the console prints "collision happened" many many times.

Here is how i declare physics bodys for each SKSpriteNode

```
dragonNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: dragonNode.texture!, size: CGSizeMake(dragonNode.size.width, dragonNode.size.height))
dragonNode.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false              
dragonNode.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
dragonNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = dragonCategory
dragonNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = bulletCategory
dragonNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = bulletCategory

bulletNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: texture, size: texture.size())
bulletNode.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
bulletNode.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
bulletNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = bulletCategory
bulletNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = dragonCategory
bulletNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = dragonCategory
```

This is one of the last things i need to fix for my game to be completed so if anyone can help that would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because theoretically your game is running at 60 frames per second. So every 60th of a second it is detecting the collision and printing the warning. You haven't put any code into say stop detecting this collision. You could always put a flag on the object

```
dragonNode.collided = true
```

and then detect for the collision and the flag

```
if (firstBody.categoryBitMask == bulletCategory && secondBody.categoryBitMask == dragonCategory || firstBody.categoryBitMask == dragonCategory && secondBody.categoryBitMask == bulletCategory) && dragonNode.collided != true {
    dragonNode.collided = true
    print("collision happened")
}
```

this way the collision only fires once

Comment: do i need to set dragonNode.collided to false to allow this to reset?

Comment: there i've added a code example of what you can do. Obviously you will have to create a property on the dragonNode that you can write to (like "collided") or find another variable to write to to check. You will also have to find a way to reset the variable so detections can be detected again later.

Comment: Often times in games what the developers do is when there is a collision they set a flag saying they player has been hit, flash the player saying that they have been hit (make the sprite flash red for a second), then they put a wait for duration action around 1.0 second and then reset the flag back to false

Comment: glad it helped, sorry for sending the answer in a bunch of edits. I did't want to leave you hanging for an answer while I thought of what to say

Comment: you killed it man! my program is now only detecting a single collision. And yeah i saw the answer continuously updating with your edits haha